# Javascript code for remove image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make this Javascript code to when I click "remove image" link , it remove the image. Please help me.

```
<script>
function previewFile(){

   var preview = document.querySelector('img'); 
   var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
   var reader  = new FileReader();

   reader.onloadend = function () {
       preview.src = reader.result;
   }
   if (file) {
       reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
   } else {
       preview.src = "";
   }
}

  previewFile();  

</script>

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<a href="#">remove image </a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not simply hide the `img` element?

Comment: Just hide the image element, or change it's source to something else. Or nothing at all.

Comment: I wann to hide imag path also

Comment: See this tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<img id='image' src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<a id='remove' href="#">remove image </a>

<script>
$(function rmv() {
    $('#remove').click(function() {
            $('#image').remove();
        }

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the image, it hides it. You should use the remove function of jQuery (or even javascript has it).

      $('#myImage').remove();

If you want to keep your old image path in case, I'd suggest use creating a array named "imageCache" and keep the image the user has seen in there, so then you'll be able to easily do animation on the image in the div without risking to "reveal" your hidden image.

Comment: (S)he wasn't asking asking for a jQuery solution

Comment: i want remove hided image path also.

Comment: "I want to make this Javascript code to when.." I'm pretty sure that s(he) wants a JS solution

Comment: jQuery is JS, but not all JS is jQuery. Maybe OP doesn't want to use jQuery, and the question is not tagged with it (just javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot add `id` attribute to that `img`, you can remove it like this with raw javascript - it assumes the image is preceding the anchor tag directly, allowing for only one text node between them:

```
function removeImage(el){
    if(!el.previousSibling.tagName){//if it is textnode like newline etc. we go one back 
        var el = el.previousSibling;
    }
    if(el.previousSibling.tagName && el.previousSibling.tagName=='IMG'){
        el.previousSibling.remove();
    }
}

<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<a href="#" onclick="removeImage(this);">remove image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep img element in div and assign id to both this element

```
   <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<div id="imgDiv">    <img id="image1" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview..."></div>
    <a href="#">remove image </a>

      </body>
    </html>

<script>
function previewFile() {

  var d = document.getElementById('imgDiv');

  var olddiv = document.getElementById("image1");

  d.removeChild(olddiv);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="" id="image" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<a href="#" onclick="foo()">remove image </a>
```

JS:

```
function foo(){
    var image =  document.getElementById("image");
     if (image != null)
     {
          image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
     }
}
```